# Webscraping an alternate version/hidden item from a webpage using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape information (points scored, tackles made, time played, position, etc...) about top14 rugby players from a website.
For each player I get info from this page :
http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14/joueurs/nicholas-abendanon
For each player, I can get info for the 2015-2016 season easily, but I also need info for the 2014-2015 season.

Problem is, when I open the corresponding link (http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14/joueurs/nicholas-abendanon#season=14535) the source code is the same and the info my program scrape is the 2015-2016 data.
I can't seem to find a way to get the info for previous seasons even though it appears on the webpage.
Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Here is my code for the player I gave as an example.

```
import bs4
from lxml import html
import requests
import string
import _pickle as pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
dic={}
url_player='http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14/joueurs/nicholas-abendanon'
page = requests.get(url_player)
html=page.content
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
body=parsed_html.body
saison14_15=body.find('a',attrs={'data-title':'Saison 2014-2015'})
link=saison14_15['href']
url_season='http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14/joueurs/nicholas-abendanon'+link
page_season = requests.get(url_season)
html_season=page_season.content
parsed_html_season = BeautifulSoup(html_season)
body_season=parsed_html_season.body

dic['nom']=body_season.find('h1',attrs={'id':'page-title'}).text
dic[body_season.find('span',attrs=     {'class':'title'}).text]=body_season.find('span',attrs={'class':'text'}).text
info1=body_season.find('ul',attrs={'class':'infos-list small-bold'})
try:
    for item in info1.findAll('li'):
        dic[item.find('span',attrs={'class':'title'}).text]=item.find('span',attrs={'class':'text'}).text 
    info2=body_season.find('ul',attrs={'class':'fluid-block-grid-3 team-stats'})
    if info2 is not None :
        for item in info2.findAll('li'):   
            dic[item.find('span',attrs={'class':'title'}).text]=item.find('span',attrs={'class':'text'}).text
    info3=body_season.find('ul',attrs={'class':'number-list small-block-grid-2'})
    if info3 is not None :
        for item in info3.findAll('li'):   
            dic[item.find('span',attrs={'class':'title'}).text]=item.find('span',attrs={'class':'text'}).text
except:
    dic=dic`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose the 2014-2015 season, the page makes an AJAX request to

```
http://www.lnr.fr/ajax_player_stats_detail?player=33249&compet_type=1&=undefined&season=14535&_filter_current_tab_id=panel-filter-season&ajax-target-selector=%23player_stats_detail_block
```

If you then switch back to 2015-2016, it makes an AJAX request to

```
http://www.lnr.fr/ajax_player_stats_detail?player=33249&compet_type=1&=undefined&season=18505&_filter_current_tab_id=panel-filter-season&ajax-target-selector=%23player_stats_detail_block
```

Each request returns a chunk of HTML which gets inserted into the page.

If you can figure out the parameters needed for `player` and `season`, I suggest you request the data directly (without loading the parent page at all).

Comment: It looks like it is working just fine scrapping the URL you metionned ! Thanks. However, could you explain me how you found these ? Or somewhere I could learn more about Ajax requests. I would like to be able to solve the problem on my own next time.

Comment: I use Firefox with the Firebug plugin; the Firebug console has a Network tab which shows any ajax requests the page makes. It is a fantastic tool for digging into how a page works.

Comment: I am bothering you again. I have a new issue. I am trying to scrap the 'XV de départ' player names from this page: [http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14/matchs/21-08-15-toulon-racing-92#fndtn-panel-live-compo-equipe]. As you can see it is inside a collapsed table. I used the chrome 'inspect' plugin but can't find any ajax request or other leading to the html code that contains this info. Do you know how it can be retrieved ?

Comment: That was a bit tricky but I found it. They are using some sort of live data linking; in the page you see `<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {new Live.LiveControler($('.page-content'), "\/fdmi?nid=361667",` etc. If you get `http://www.lnr.fr/fdmi?nid=361667` it returns json; the data you want is in `data["teams"][0]["lineup"]` and `data["teams"][1]["lineup"]`.